# Is there a way to access the class name from a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to set some default class variables in a base class so all subclasses are guaranteed to have a default value. Some of these I'd like to be dynamic based upon the subclass (`DISPLAY_NAME` in the example below). The use of `__qualname__` in `_ExtensionBase` doesn't work because it sets `DISPLAY_NAME` to the static string "_ExtensionBase".

Is there a simpler way to do this, or any issues with the way I've found below? I haven't stumbled into any, bit it feels like pushing some limits of the intended uses of `property` and `classmethod`

```
class _ExtensionBase:
    PRIORITY: float = 1.0 
    VERSION_STR: str = 'n/a'
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    def DISPLAY_NAME(cls) -> str:
        return cls.__name__


class ConcreteSubclass(_ExtensionBase): pass

assert ConcreteSubclass.DISPLAY_NAME == "ConcreteSubclass"
```

Comment: AFAIK this should work just fine.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: What you have makes sense. "access the class name from a class variable" does not, because variables don't "access" - they are **just a name** for an *already existing thing*. (Also, because "class variable" doesn't make sense - you presumably mean class *attribute*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the note in Python 3.11's entry on `@classmethod` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod))

> Changed in version 3.9: Class methods can now wrap other descriptors
> such as `property()`.
>
> Changed in version 3.10: Class methods now inherit the method
> attributes (`__module__`, `__name__`, `__qualname__`,
> `__doc__` and `__annotations__`) and have a new
> `__wrapped__` attribute.
>
> Changed in version 3.11: Class methods can no longer wrap other
> descriptors such as `property()`.

This solution is only supported for a limited subset of python versions 3.9 and 3.10 and was buggy in those leading to it's removal in 3.11. See the 3.11 deprecation notes ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#deprecated)) and the Github issue discussion ([gh-89519](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89519)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ConcreteSubclass.__name__
```

Comment: I suppose I didn't make it clear in my original post. the reason for not looking up `__name__` on the subclass is that I want to ensure all subclasses to have the `DISPLAY_NAME` member (baring attribute deletion of course) which can be customized but has a sane default. So a future class may be something like  `BatFileExtensionRunner(_ExtensionBase): DISPLAY_NAME = pathlib.Path(batFile).stem;`